# How can I order has_one association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_one :product
end
```

I want to sort my orders using name of products. I tried doing as suggested by other SO answers.

```
Order.last.line_items.includes(:product).order('products.name ASC')
```

But it throws an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you defined `default_scope` in model `LineItem` something like this:

`default_scope { order(created_at: :asc) }`

And `Order.last.line_items` will order by `created_at`, but table `products` also has column `created_at`, so *`column reference "created_at" is ambiguous`*.

---

To fix this, there are some options:

- Define `default_scope` explicitly: `default_scope { order('line_items ASC') }`
- Remove the order clause by using: `unscope(:order)` or `reorder(nil)`

`Order.last.line_items.includes(:product).unscope(:order).order('products.name ASC')`

Comment: Thank you. But I haven't defined any default_scope in line_item. And even if I do the second option it says undefined method `unscope' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000bcd3060

Comment: How about model “Product”. default_scope can be used in has_many also, eg: has_many :abc, -> { order(:created_at) }. [unscope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/úncope)

Answer (score 0):

There is ambiguous info in your SQL. Try to add [references](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) into your code:

```
Order.last.line_items.includes(:product).order('products.name ASC').references(:product)
```